# How to convert text file with delimiters as fields into solr document

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

I have a **text** file which consist of the following data:

```
andy~1234;M~64365113~2P3VWU3H10~~
mike~4152;M~64365113~2P3VWU3H10~0.6~MG
lesa~4512;F,PM~~N/A~16~MG
riky~7845;M,PM2~~N/A~3.99~MG
```

I wish to convert it into a solr document in the following manner :

> 1. Each row is considered as 1 `<doc>` document in solr.
> 2. '~' is a delimiter which means fields `<field>` of document.

Do I need to use a DataImportHandler for handling these kind of files? which kind of DataImportHandler is useful. I've gone through [LineEntityProcessor](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#LineEntityProcessor), but i didn't understand how I can use it for my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you know the field names (lines contain just the values), here's an example of how you can do that using a FileDatasource + LineEntityProcessor + ScriptTransformer:

```
<dataConfig>  
    <dataSource encoding="UTF-8" type="FileDataSource" name="file-datasource"/>
    <script><![CDATA[
        function parse(row)    
        {
            var rawLine = row.get("rawLine")

            // Split the rawLine 
            // And for each field

            // row.put('fieldName', fieldValue);                    

            return row;
        }
    ]]></script>        
    <document>
        <entity name="jc"
            processor="LineEntityProcessor"
            url="file:///your.path.file.here"
            dataSource="file-datasource"
            transformer="script:parse">
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Comment: thank you for reply, can this approach may lead to any performance loop falls for bulk data? and what is in case of any failure occurs -is it rollback the transactions?

Comment: commit and optimize procedures follow the general rule for SOLR and DataImportHandler. You can control them explicitly by request parameters or with autocommit (time or documents basis). About performance: the whole process is sequential so if you want parallelism you should write a simple multithread indexing client. And last...thanks for the "thank", you're welcome, but if you think the answer is right, you should accept it. Best, Andrea